# How to expand and less the Box div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to expand and less the slider div for only that box where the user click.
I am able to do that but when I click read more all the boxes is expanding that is I do not want.
I want only particular box expand and rest of the boxes do not expand.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<style>
  #readmore1 {display: none;}
  #readmore2 {display: none;}
  #readmore3 {display: none;}
</style>




     <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="carousel-item active">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 testSliderBox">
            <img class="testiSliderImageRound" src="assets/img/mbbs/m/internal-germany.jpg" alt="testimonial-PGmedica"  width="120" height="120">
            <h4 class="testiSliderHeading">Mark Allen</h4>
            <p class="testiSliderPara">
              <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span id="readdots1">...</span><span id="readmore1">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</span>
              <a class="float-right" onclick="myFunction1()" id="myBtn1" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Read more</a>
              <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i>

            </p>
      </div> <!-- inside col-md-4 end Slider 1 -->
      
      <div class="col-md-4 testSliderBox">
            <img class="testiSliderImageRound" src="assets/img/mbbs/m/internal-germany.jpg" alt="testimonial-PGmedica"  width="120" height="120">
            <h4 class="testiSliderHeading">Mark Allen</h4>
            <p class="testiSliderPara">
              <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span id="readdots2">...</span><span id="readmore2">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</span>

              <a class="float-right" onclick="myFunction2()" id="myBtn2" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Read more</a>
              <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i>
            </p>
      </div> <!-- inside col-md-4 end Slider 1 -->
      
     <div class="col-md-4 testSliderBox">
            <img class="testiSliderImageRound" src="assets/img/mbbs/m/internal-germany.jpg" alt="testimonial-PGmedica"  width="120" height="120">
            <h4 class="testiSliderHeading">Mark Allen</h4>
            <p class="testiSliderPara">
              <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span id="readdots1">...</span><span id="readmore1">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</span>
              <a class="float-right" onclick="myFunction3()" id="myBtn3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Read more</a>
              <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i>
            </p>
      </div> <!-- inside col-md-4 end Slider 1 -->
      
    </div> <!-- inside row end -->
  </div> <!-- inside container end -->
</div>


<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
</div>



 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next" style="width:85px;">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 </div>



  <script>
   function myFunction1() {
   var dots = document.getElementById("readdots1");
   var moreText = document.getElementById("readmore1");
   var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
   dots.style.display = "inline";
   btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
   moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
   dots.style.display = "none";
   btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
   moreText.style.display = "inline";
   }
   }


 function myFunction2() {
 var dots = document.getElementById("readdots2");
 var moreText = document.getElementById("readmore2");
 var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

 if (dots.style.display === "none") {
   dots.style.display = "inline";
  btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
  moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
   dots.style.display = "none";
   btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
   moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
  }


function myFunction3() {
 var dots = document.getElementById("readdots3");
 var moreText = document.getElementById("readmore3");
 var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

 if (dots.style.display === "none") {
  dots.style.display = "inline";
  btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
  moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dots.style.display = "none";
  btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
  moreText.style.display = "inline";
}
}
</script>
```

I want when I click "readmore" only that particular box expand and rest will not expand.
Kindly check what I am doing wrong.
Your suggestions are welcome

Comment: you copied the `JS` from w3schools??

Comment: Please remove the jquery tag, because you're not using jquery in this example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked from your answer right away except when I clicked the third box, where you had a typo. You wrote `readdots1` and `readmore1`, when it should be `readdots3` and so on.

```js
function myFunction1() {
   var dots = document.getElementById("readdots1");
   var moreText = document.getElementById("readmore1");
   var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
   dots.style.display = "inline";
   btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
   moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
   dots.style.display = "none";
   btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
   moreText.style.display = "inline";
   }
   }


 function myFunction2() {
 var dots = document.getElementById("readdots2");
 var moreText = document.getElementById("readmore2");
 var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

 if (dots.style.display === "none") {
   dots.style.display = "inline";
  btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
  moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
   dots.style.display = "none";
   btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
   moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
  }


function myFunction3() {
 var dots = document.getElementById("readdots3");
 var moreText = document.getElementById("readmore3");
 var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

 if (dots.style.display === "none") {
  dots.style.display = "inline";
  btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
  moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dots.style.display = "none";
  btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
  moreText.style.display = "inline";
}
}
```

```html
<style>
  #readmore1 {display: none;}
  #readmore2 {display: none;}
  #readmore3 {display: none;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="carousel-item active">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 testSliderBox">
            <img class="testiSliderImageRound" src="assets/img/mbbs/m/internal-germany.jpg" alt="testimonial-PGmedica"  width="120" height="120">
            <h4 class="testiSliderHeading">Mark Allen</h4>
            <p class="testiSliderPara">
              <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span id="readdots1">...</span><span id="readmore1">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</span>
              <a class="float-right" onclick="myFunction1()" id="myBtn1" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Read more</a>
              <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i>

            </p>
      </div> <!-- inside col-md-4 end Slider 1 -->
      
      <div class="col-md-4 testSliderBox">
            <img class="testiSliderImageRound" src="assets/img/mbbs/m/internal-germany.jpg" alt="testimonial-PGmedica"  width="120" height="120">
            <h4 class="testiSliderHeading">Mark Allen</h4>
            <p class="testiSliderPara">
              <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span id="readdots2">...</span><span id="readmore2">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</span>

              <a class="float-right" onclick="myFunction2()" id="myBtn2" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Read more</a>
              <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i>
            </p>
      </div> <!-- inside col-md-4 end Slider 1 -->
      
     <div class="col-md-4 testSliderBox">
            <img class="testiSliderImageRound" src="assets/img/mbbs/m/internal-germany.jpg" alt="testimonial-PGmedica"  width="120" height="120">
            <h4 class="testiSliderHeading">Mark Allen</h4>
            <p class="testiSliderPara">
              <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span id="readdots3">...</span><span id="readmore3">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</span>
              <a class="float-right" onclick="myFunction3()" id="myBtn3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Read more</a>
              <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C8C2C2"></i>
            </p>
      </div> <!-- inside col-md-4 end Slider 1 -->
      
    </div> <!-- inside row end -->
  </div> <!-- inside container end -->
</div>


<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
</div>



 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next" style="width:85px;">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Also, there is one major thing to drastically shorten and improve your code, but that's out of this site topics. Please, go to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask to review this code.

Comment: @Dexygen in the above code the  slider is not working. When slider working the other box also expand like in the image https://ibb.co/bd9jh4y , this is the problem. This is the above same code with working slider. I want when I click on read more only that box expand not other with working slider.

Comment: @ Vlastimil Lisák in the above code the slider is not working. When slider working the other box also expand like in the image ibb.co/bd9jh4y , this is the problem. This is the above same code with working slider. I want when I click on read more only that box expand not other with working slider.